# Why is Amazon's Vendor Central API not giving POs changed on a certain date?

Tags: api, amazon-product-api

I'm using Amazon's Vendor Central API to find all purchase orders changed on a given date.  The API runs fine, but it seems to be excluding some results.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Example:

I want to know of any POs changed on 12/10.  I know PO 8ZTZJAZD was changed on that date because if I search for the specific PO I get a changed date of 12/10:

[image]

However, when I run the API for any POs on 12/10, I don't get any results:

[image]

Why does a record clearly changed on 12/10 not coming up when I ask for all records changed after 12/10 12 a.m. and before 12/10 11:59 p.m.?

Comment: Honestly it just seems like large portions of this API just does not work.....I am working with the direct fulfilment API and not the retail but pretty much anything that requires before/after date parameters will return strange results leaving out things that should be there and including things that shouldn't. With generating shipping labels I pretty much have to use single request because if I use a range there are always labels missing..not to mention the packing slip API seems to just not work at all. (as a side question does post man let you sign your request and generate tokens?)

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2021, the whole vendor central/direct fulfillment API system is extremely delicate and riddled with bugs, this is unfortunately just something you'll have to deal with using business logic.